# Used 'new' operator in LINQ to SQL query, but same instance is referenced in every result

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Can anyone explain the behavior I am seeing in the minimal code example below?  It seems that for a given field or property, the same two instances of the `Entry` class are being reused in each iteration of the LINQ to SQL query, even though I use the `new` operator.  The same problem does not show up for LINQ to objects queries.  I created a C# console application project using .NET Framework 4 and connecting to a SQL Server 2005 Enterprise database.

```
public class Set
{
    public Entry Field;
    public Entry Property { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(); // just create a simple dbml with some table from some database
        var resultQuery = (
            from x in dc.SomeTable
            select new Set()
            {
                Field = new Entry(),
                Property = new Entry()
            }
        );
        var sets = resultQuery.ToArray();
        Test(sets);

        var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
        var sourceQuery = (
            from x in source
            select new Set()
            {
                Field = new Entry(),
                Property = new Entry()
            }
        );
        var sets2 = sourceQuery.ToArray();
        Test(sets2);
    }

    static void Test(Set[] sets)
    {
        var f = sets[0].Field;
        Console.WriteLine(sets.All(x => object.Equals(x.Field, f)));
        var p = sets[0].Property;
        Console.WriteLine(sets.All(x => object.Equals(x.Property, p)));
        Console.Writeline(sets.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(f, p));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output of `Test()` for the LINQ to SQL query is

```
True
True
1362
False
```

which indicates that for all of the `Set` objects produced, all the `Field` members point to the same single `Entry` instance and all the `Property` members point to the same single `Entry` instance.  I.e., the same instance is reused for a respective member in every iteration of the query.

The output of `Test()` for the LINQ to objects query is

```
False
False
10
False
```

which indicates that a new distinct instance is created in each iteration of the query.

Is the LINQ to SQL behavior expected or a bug?  Does anyone know if this happens with the Entity Framework?

Comment: Are you sure `dc.SomeTable` has more than one row? Can you add a `Console.WriteLine(sets.Count());`?

Comment: Good point. Yes, in my test it has thousands of rows; `sets.Length > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or if and why this is expected in LINQ to SQL. I can only answer your last question if that also happens with Entity Framework.

The answer is: No.

With EF you have to use object initializer syntax though when you instantiate the `Entry` objects. Using the default constructor leads to an exception:

```
var resultQuery = (
    from x in dc.SomeTable
    select new Set
    {
        Field = new Entry { Name = "X" },
        Property = new Entry { Name = "X" }
    }
);
```

It doesn't matter how you initialize. Using the code above (and with 4 rows in a small test table) I get this output with your test program:

```
False
False
4
False

False
False
10
False
```

It looks that there is a big difference between LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework regarding object materialization during projections.

(I've tested with EF 4.1/DbContext.)

**Edit**

If I take the modified query in my code snippet above also for your LINQ to SQL query and watch the generated SQL I get the following:

```
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [t0]
```

Whereas the same with LINQ to Entites creates this query:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
N'X' AS [C2], 
N'X' AS [C3]
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
```

My interpretation is that LINQ to SQL parses the projection code and queries only columns for property values which depend on the "row variable" x. All other properties are filled on the client when the objects get materialized. If an object does not depend on a column value at all, LINQ to SQL creates a single constant object and reuses it in the whole result collection.

In constrast to this Entity Framework also sends constant values (independent of x) to the database server. The values get send back to the client and EF treats those values as if they were column values and updates the properties of the objects in the projection.

This leads also to the big difference that something like this...

```
Random random = new Random();
var resultQuery = (
    from x in dc.SomeTable
    select new Set
    {
        Field = new Entry { ID = random.Next() },
        Property = new Entry { Name = "X" }
    }
);
```

...works in LINQ to SQL because apparently the random function value (which is independent of x) is evaluated on the client and then assigned to the property. But EF wants to translate the right side of the property assignment into SQL and send it as SQL fragment to the database server - which fails and leads to the infamous "*...cannot translate into store expression...*" exception.

**Edit 2**

BTW: The last code snippet above still creates only a single `Field` instance in the whole collection: `random.Next()` is only evaluated once (and also the constructor of `Entry` is only called once for the `Field` object). This now is indeed confusing because writing such code one would expect that you want to have a random value for each row returned from the database. It's not the case.